# Issue installing package 'quantmod'

Tags: r, package, quantmod

I keep having this error when I try to install `quantmod` package from the CRAN repository:

```
install.packages("quantmod")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Dominic/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘xts’, ‘zoo’, ‘TTR’

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘xts’ ‘zoo’ ‘TTR’ ‘quantmod’
  These will not be installed
```

I also downloaded the .gz files locally and install but get the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Dominic/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies 'xts', 'zoo', 'TTR' are not available for package 'quantmod'
* removing 'C:/Users/Dominic/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/quantmod'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Dominic\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/Dominic/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMnw2yn/downloaded_packages/quantmod_0.4-5.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Dominic/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMnw2yn/downloaded_packages/quantmod_0.4-5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here is the output of `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200) 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252 

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
```

Comment: Try to individually install `xts`, `zoo` and `TTR` packages first.

Comment: You should try a different CRAN mirror. Windows binaries should be available for all those packages. Also, please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2

Comment: What mirror are you using?

Comment: CRAN repository. Interestingly enough, I tried installing all of this on another of my desktops from the repository and it worked fine.

Comment: CRAN is the *Comprehensive R Archive Network*, so your response doesn't answer the question of which mirror you're using. I expected you to provide the mirror URL.

Comment: I had the same issue. Choosing a different a different mirror chooseCRANmirror() solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

1- Download the latest version from:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/quantmod_0.4-8.zip

2- unzip it in your package directory. It can be found with:
.libPaths()

3- Make sure the folder name reads "quantmod" in your package directory.

4- Type in library("quantmod")